# What are the methods to define a inline replacement in code?

Tags: c++

I want to define `(var-1) > 0? var - 1: 0` as a inline replace. such as

`#define MAX(VAR) as (VAR-1) > 0? VAR- 1: 0`

like `using` etc?

Comment: No, you don't want to define an inline replacement. What you want is a function, or possibly a function template. If someone passes an expression with side effects to your macro, those side effects might happen twice.

Comment: @Caleth are macro defined in cpp acts globally on the project? or is it specifically to that cpp?

Comment: If you are a beginner at C++, you are not in a position to second guess whether inlining a particular function is an optimisation or a pessimisation. Leave that up to the implementation.

Comment: A macro replaces matching text that follows its definition (up to it's undefinition)

Comment: "like `using` etc"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 6):

You define a function, and leave it up to the implementation to appropriately inline it.

```
 constexpr int max(int var) { return (var - 1) > 0 ? (var - 1) : 0; }
```

Aside: `max` isn't a great name for this, I'd suggest something like `clamp_positive`

Comment: i suggest to choose a better name, or rather just use [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use, well, the `inline` keyword:

```cpp
inline int max(int var) 
{ 
    return (var - 1) > 0 ? (var - 1) : 0; 
}
```

But, this will not force the inline, it will just suggest the compiler that you should make this function inline. The compiler can refuse your suggest, or make it inline even if you don't use the inline keyword

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is of #defines for preprocessors are simply

```
#define Name(...args) (replacement)
```

without `as` or `=`

So your definition would be

```c
#define MAX(VAR) (VAR-1) > 0? VAR- 1: 0
```

In my experience I always find that it is useful to wrap defines like these with parenthesis to avoid ambiguity, you never know where this will be replace for instance `MAX(x)*5` would give `(x-1) > 0 ? x-1 : 0*5` that is the same as `MAX(x)`.

```c
#define MAX(VAR) ((VAR-1) > 0? VAR- 1: 0)
```

If you want to use a function as in suggested in the comments

```cpp
int MAX(int v){
  return (v-1)>0? v-1:0;
}
```

Or as a template function

```cpp
template<typename Tp>
Tp MAX(const _Tp &v){
  return (v-1)>0? v-1:0;
}
```

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them - there is an immense amount of other names to choose from.

Comment: Thank you @molbdnilo, could you please point me a reference about these conventions, please?

Comment: It's not a convention, it is a hard rule specified in The Standard.

Comment: Is the standard available on the web?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/? I never saw a standard that everybody refers to. I only read the compiler messages, and random internet pages. This is for me like the bible was to the medieval people.

Comment: I use the _Tp for template types precisely because it is how the STL methods do.

Comment: You shouldn't read random internet pages, you should read [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). And the library implementation is not an example of what to do. Everything in there is an internal implementation detail.

Comment: Sorry, in your previous comment you suggested me to use google, now you are suggesting books, but you never shown me where it says that I should not start with _[A-Z].

Comment: I am not asking for books here, I only want you to show how is this rule stated.

Comment: See [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name).

Comment: Thank you, so that means that, a compiler could extend the C++ language and assign a different meaning to any of those identifier? Code like [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6180f5c8d6d1dc7b6634c41a46f0f8f5ca2e5b9d/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/set#L90) are explicitly violating that specification, targeting code for one specific compiler?

Comment: The code you're looking at *is* "the implementation", which is explicitly allowed to do that (that's what "reserved to the implementation" means). Even if it weren't specifically allowed, the library implementation is allowed to do things that users of it aren't.

Comment: @Bob -- the reason for using `_Tp` in the implementation is **exactly** that the name is reserved for use by the implementation. That protects the standard library headers from code that, say, does `#define _Tp my_type`, which would break the standard library headers. It also can go the other way; the standard library headers might define a macro for internal use, and you don't want to use the name of that macro in your code.